# Recognize downloaded file names from google patents

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a csv file with about 500 hundred links from google patents and I iterate them in scrapy in order to download the csv file from each link (There is a download link in each link). I have successfully implement this but what I want to do now is a way from the html markup to discover the name from each downloaded file in order to edit with python. An example link is this https://patents.google.com/?q=O1C(%3dCCCC1C)C&oq=O1C(%3dCCCC1C)C. The name for the downloaded file is generated dynamically so is there a way to find it out?

Comment: > what I want to do now is a way from the html markup to discover the name from each downloaded file in order to edit with python 
Explain this a bit more, also post an example of what you have now and what you want.

Comment: If you visit the link I have posted there is a download link (top right corner). I want to find from the html markup the name of the downloaded file. When I go to the a html tag in href there is not the name. How is it possible to find it out. Sorry for bad english

Comment: Ok, to be clear, you want to download all the pdf files from https://patents.google.com/?q=O1C(%3dCCCC1C)C&oq=O1C(%3dCCCC1C)C using scrapy right?.

Comment: No, I have downloaded the files, with scrapy, but I do not know how to find the names of the files in order to open with python. It seems that the names are generated dynamically and there are not in href tag

Comment: Please try to improve your question. edit it and post what you have(with examples), what you tried and what you want.

Answer (score 1):

the name is just the date : gp-search-20210816-142027.csv 2021-08-16 14:20:27.

Comment: How is it possible to take the name programmatically?

Comment: if you haven't recorded the names/dates then you can't, but you can easily walk a directory with python

Comment: How can I 'walk' a directory with files that I do not know tha names in python?

Comment: the [doc for os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) should be a good start

Answer (score 0):

As a demo of what you may want to do, and **if** I'm understanding the question you could follow the direction in the code below. Note: It is only a suggested idea and it only scrapes the PDF links from the first page to show the idea.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd


# next 12 lines have the job of getting the links of the PDF files from the URL below
# just the FIRST PAGE as a demo
url = "https://patents.google.com/?q=O1C(%3dCCCC1C)C&oq=O1C(%3dCCCC1C)C"
path = r'chromedriver'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
links = []
print('# this just gets the FIRST PAGE for a demo')
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'pdfLink style-scope search-result-item'}):
    print(link['href'])
    links.append(link['href'])


# next 11 lines cover creating a dataframe from the downloaded CSV file on the Google search page
# and a 2nd frame for the links scraped.  The two frames are eventually joined by a partial match
# of the 'result_link' from the first frame and a partial match of the filename of the pdf URL from the 2nd frame
pattern = r'/([A-Z]{2}\w{7})'
df = pd.read_csv('gp-search-20210816-190925.csv', skiprows=1)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
df['partial_file_name'] = df['result_link'].str.extract(pattern)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['pdf_link'])
df1['partial_file_name'] = df1['pdf_link'].str.extract(pattern)
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
df['filename'] = df['pdf_link'].str.extract(r'/([A-Z]{2}\w+)\.')
del df['partial_file_name']
print('\n\n', df.columns)

# 12 columns in total but for demo showing five
df[['filename', 'id', 'title', 'filing/creation_date', 'pdf_link']].head(
```

)

**Outputs:**

```
# this just gets the FIRST PAGE for a demo
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/01/d1/77/6b0b7640eaccda/US7550931.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/a2/32/15/69cf7713e8e2bf/JP2008525498A.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/7e/6b/b7/001a8040e216ee/TWI686424B.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/0f/14/fc/ecb56564f14f6b/WO2005009447A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/95/fd/d5/ed4fe960bdec1c/KR20140096378A.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/7e/29/01/231cc0813a0f6a/US5026677.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/ff/f9/c9/7b775d6534d9cb/EP0628427A1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/bd/b3/ba/f38866e0b298e2/KR960004857B1.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/79/e2/11/78aea87078687f/US5942486.pdf
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/62/f5/da/f291e7552a45a6/US5142089.pdf


 Index(['id', 'title', 'assignee', 'inventor/author', 'priority_date',
       'filing/creation_date', 'publication_date', 'grant_date', 'result_link',
       'representative_figure_link', 'pdf_link', 'filename'],
      dtype='object')

    filename          id                   title                                              filing/creation_date      pdf_link
0   US7550931         US-7550931-B2        Controlled lighting methods and apparatus          2007-03-15                https://patentimages.stora.....ccda/US7550931.pdf
1   JP2008525498A     JP-2008525498-A      Enzyme modulators and therapy                      2005-12-23                https://patentimages.stora....f/JP2008525498A.pdf
2   TWI686424B        TW-I686424-B         Polymer containing triazine ring and compositi...  2016-01-15                https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/7e...
3   WO2005009447A1    WO-2005009447-A1     Single dose fast dissolving azithromycin           2004-07-22                https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/0f...
4   KR20140096378A    KR-20140096378-A     Low chloride compositions of olefinically func...  2012-11-19                https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/95...
```

It shows a way you can get the filenames, links, and other fields aligned.